# svg elements reset on hide/show in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, svg

I have 3 SVG `<object>` elements representing 3 differents floors of a building. In the bottom I have 3 buttons to navigate between them that do a simple `hide()` and `show()`.

[image: map]

When I load the page a script setups some interactive elements in the svg, but when i switch between floors with the navigation buttons the interactive svg elements resets losing its functionality.

**interactive elements**
[image: interactive elements]

How can I prevent this? the script seems to be working on firefox.

Here's the code that hides/show the floors.

```
function showMap(mapId){
  var map = (typeof(mapId)=="string")? $('#'+mapId) : $(mapId);
  if(!map.is(':visible')){
    maps.hide(); // hides all svg objects
    map.show();  // display the selected one
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is a "feature" of Chrome. "display: none" (including css way) completely ruins all interactions with SVG.
Use size or position instead:

```
jQuery.fn.weirdHide = function() {
    $(this).css("width", 0)
        .css("height", 0)
        .css("position", "absolute")
        .css("left", "-9999px");
}

jQuery.fn.weirdShow = function() {
    $(this).css("width", "")
        .css("height", "")
        .css("position", "")
        .css("left", "");
}

$("#map").weirdHide();
$("#map").weirdShow();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm finding that it's only the first SVG in the DOM that is messing things up, so what I did was prepending and SVG with size zero, then I could use hide/show without problems.